# Iframe stop break out, but than allow it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Right what I want to do is, display a username and password on the top of a page so you can enter it and than continue on as normal. (I don't care if it stays or breaks out of the iframe at this point)

A number of people log in the same account for teachial details, So currently we have a html page with the user name and password as well as a link to the log in page. I have tried just passing the varibles onto the login page but that a no go sadly.

To add insult to injury this has to be done in html, because it all run from a network drive (I know it a pile of crap on crap it is not mine, nothing I can do about it)

Currently I can stopped the login pages jumping out of the iframe, but then of course you can't login. Any ideas or is it impossible with the limitations in place?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Username: <b>******</b></p>
    <p>Password: <b>******</b></p>
    <iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" name="Embedded Frame" src="LINK" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
<body>
</html>
```

Edit: I should add that I have no control over the login pages they are run my a number of different people across the world. I be happy with just displaying the user name and password so it can be easily copied in to the field

Answer (score 0):

First of all your  end tag needs to be like this 
Also try this instead of your code! :)
:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javaScript">

    function True/False() { //what youwant to do put it in here in javascript form:) try an if statement it should work if not use a switch! 
    } 
    function Input1() { 
      //Connect to whatever value you want it to load on. 
    } 
      function Input() 
      { 
        //password value goes here 
      }

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <br>
  <br>
  <center>


    <div id="Input1()">
      <input type="Username" value="" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="Input2()">
      <input type="Password" Value="" />
    </div>
    <!-- in the onclick make a function for it to load-->

    <div id="True/False()">
      <input type="button" type="button" value="login" onclick="" />

    </div>
  </center>


 <!-- you need to make this a function of True/false and tell it to load when to load. This is an error frame lol.
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" name="Embedded Frame" src="LINK" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
-->
</body>

</html>
```